# Solution of $\begin{cases} y(t)=z''\\ z(t)=y'' \end{cases}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

> Solve $$\begin{cases}
> y(t)=z''\\
> z(t)=y''
> \end{cases}$$
>
> $y(0) = z(0) = 0$
>
> $y(\pi/2) = z(\pi/2) = 1 $

My attempt:

$$\begin{cases}
y(t)=z''\\
z(t)=y''
\end{cases}\Rightarrow y(t)=y^{(4)}$$

The roots of corresponding characteristic equation are $1,-1,i,-i$. That's why

$$y(t)=c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos t+c_{4}\sin t$$

Using initial conditions, we get $$\begin{cases}
0=c_{1}+c_{2}+c_{3}\\
1=c_{1}e^{\pi/2}+c_{2}e^{-\pi/2}+c_{4}
\end{cases}$$

My question: how to solve this system of 2 equations in 4 variables?

> The answer is supposed to be
>   $$y(t)=z(t)=\frac{e^{t}-e^{-t}}{e^{\pi/2}-e^{-\pi/2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have *four* initial conditions, giving *four* equations. As $z = y''$, in addition to $y(0) = 0$ and $y(\frac \pi 2) = 1$, you have
$$ y''(0) = 0 \iff c_1 + c_2 -c_3 = 0 $$
and 
$$ y''(\textstyle\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0 \iff c_1e^{\frac \pi 2} + c_2e^{-\frac \pi 2} - c_4 = 0 $$
This (together with your two equations above) gives 
$$ c_1 + c_2 = c_3 = 0, \qquad c_1e^{\frac \pi 2} + c_2e^{-\frac\pi 2} = c_4 = 0 $$
So 
$$ c_1 = -c_2 = \frac 1{e^{\frac\pi 2} - e^{-\frac{\pi}2}}, \qquad c_3 = c_4 = 0 $$

Comment: I didn't notice that, thank you!